# Confused by `--default-remote-prefix` flag in snakemake for kubernetes on Google Cloud

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, snakemake

I'm trying to run a bioinformatics pipeline using Snakemake on GoogleCloud. The first two steps are:

1. Download the reads from ENA
2. Run `bbmap`'s clumpify on the data.

The two rules look like this:

```
def get_fwd_url(wildcard):
    return samples.loc[wildcard, 'fwd'].values[0]

def get_rev_url(wildcard):
    return samples.loc[wildcard, 'rev'].values[0]

rule get_reads:
    output:
        fwd=temp("samples/{sample}/fwd.gz"),
        rev=temp("samples/{sample}/rev.gz")
    threads: 1
    params:
        fwd_url=get_fwd_url,
        rev_url=get_rev_url
    log:
        "logs/{sample}.get_reads.log"
    benchmark:
        "benchmarks/{sample}.get_reads.tsv"
    shell:
        """
        wget -O {output.fwd} {params.fwd_url};
        wget -O {output.rev} {params.rev_url};
        """

rule run_bbmap_clumpify:
    input:
        raw_fwd=rules.get_reads.output.fwd,
        raw_rev=rules.get_reads.output.rev
    output:
        temp("{sample}.clumped.fq.gz")
    threads: 32
    resources:
        mem_mb=15000
    conda:
        "../envs/conda_qc_reads.yml"
    log:
        "logs/{sample}.run_bbmap_clumpify.log"
    benchmark:
        "benchmarks/{sample}.run_bbmap_clumpify.tsv"
    group: "bbtools"
    shell:
        """
            clumpify.sh -Xmx104g -eoom -da in1={input.raw_fwd} in2={input.raw_rev} out={output} dedupe optical 2>&1 | tee {log}
        """
```

When I run it locally using `snakemake -p dryrun`, it successfully builds the DAG.

```
rule get_reads:
    output: samples/196_SRF/fwd.gz, samples/196_SRF/rev.gz
    log: logs/196_SRF.get_reads.log
    jobid: 9
    benchmark: benchmarks/196_SRF.get_reads.tsv
    wildcards: sample=196_SRF


        wget -O samples/196_SRF/fwd.gz ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/run/ERR276/ERR2762138/BNA_AAXOSW_4_1_C7T1BACXX.IND15_clean.fastq.gz;
        wget -O samples/196_SRF/rev.gz ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/run/ERR276/ERR2762138/BNA_AAXOSW_4_2_C7T1BACXX.IND15_clean.fastq.gz;

rule run_bbmap_clumpify:
    input: samples/196_SRF/fwd.gz, samples/196_SRF/rev.gz
    output: 196_SRF.clumped.fq.gz
    log: logs/196_SRF.run_bbmap_clumpify.log
    jobid: 8
    benchmark: benchmarks/196_SRF.run_bbmap_clumpify.tsv
    wildcards: sample=196_SRF
    resources: mem_mb=15000


            clumpify.sh -Xmx104g -eoom -da in1=samples/196_SRF/fwd.gz in2=samples/196_SRF/rev.gz out=196_SRF.clumped.fq.gz dedupe optical 2>&1 | tee logs/196_SRF.run_bbmap_clumpify.log
```

I want to leverage Google Cloud to do this analysis, so I set up a GS bucket called `temperton-lab-wec-store`, then ran:

```
snakemake -p --kubernetes \
--use-conda -j 12 \
--default-remote-provider GS \
--default-remote-prefix temperton-lab-wec-store --dryrun
```

Building the DAG fails because the default remote prefix gets repeated over and over again in the path:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 25 of snakemake/rules/qc_reads.smk:
Missing input files for rule run_bbmap_clumpify:
temperton-lab-wec-store/temperton-lab-wec-store/samples/temperton-lab-wec-store/temperton-lab-wec-store/temperton-lab-wec-store/temperton-lab-wec-store/temperton-lab-wec-store/temperton-lab-wec-store/196_SRF/rev.gz
temperton-lab-wec-store/temperton-lab-wec-store/samples/temperton-lab-wec-store/temperton-lab-wec-store/temperton-lab-wec-store/temperton-lab-wec-store/temperton-lab-wec-store/temperton-lab-wec-store/196_SRF/fwd.gz
```

I presume I am doing something wrong in either setting the name in the output in the rules, or setting the `--default-remote-prefix` flag. However, I can't find anything in the documentation that indicates how I might fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I surmise this is a case where wildcard `{sample}` matches more than it should (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/snakemake/wVlJW9X-9EU/gSZh4U0_CQAJ, although the error is different).

Assuming you don't need to interpret the values in `{sample}` as regular expression, add before the first rule (rule `all` or however you called it) something like:

```
wildcard_constraints:
    sample= '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in SAMPLES]), # where SAMPLES is your list of samples 

rule all:
    etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found here [1](https://blog.liang2.tw/posts/2017/08/snakemake-google-cloud/#move-input-files-to-the-cloud-from-google-cloud-storage) an example where the Snakefile is modified to use the reference and FASTQ files from Google Cloud Storage.

Take a look a the example and let me know if trying that fixes the problem.

Here [2](https://blog.liang2.tw/posts/2017/08/snakemake-google-cloud/#store-output-files-on-the-cloud) is another example to use the flag --default-remote-prefix, I see nothing wrong in the way you're running the snakemake command but some settings in the rules file might be the problem.

[Move input files to the cloud (from Google Cloud Storage)](https://blog.liang2.tw/posts/2017/08/snakemake-google-cloud/#move-input-files-to-the-cloud-from-google-cloud-storage)

[Store output files on the cloud](https://blog.liang2.tw/posts/2017/08/snakemake-google-cloud/#store-output-files-on-the-cloud)